# Is "Health" ever utilized as a rejoinder or a blessing-directive?

Tags: phrase-usage

When a person in the vicinity sneezes, a German says, "health!" (gesundheit); when a Mexican (or all Spanish-speaking?) wait[er,ress] delivers food to a table, [s]he says, "health!" (salud). In what circumstance does an English speaker say, "health"? Ever?

Comment: Never heard that in English. It sounds mildly plausible to hear 'To your health!' but that's the closest. Saying just 'health' sounds weird.

Comment: What @Mitch said: *To your health!*

Comment: I suspect that many/most Americans are under the impression that "gesundheit" means "God bless you".;

Comment: A Mexican waitress is more likely to say  "_provecho_". "_Salud_" is usually used for sneezes, although _compadres_  or _cuates_ might use it when drinking.

Comment: On a lighter note, when you ask an old man/ woman or a terminally sick patient to choose between health or wealth, the likely answer would be "health"

Comment: No, not ever, as a single word.

Comment: @Monzoor If they are your "lighter notes", what are the heavy ones like?

Comment: Native English speakers also say "gesundheit" when someone sneezes - does that count?

Comment: Closely related: [What are alternative responses for when someone sneezes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31322/what-are-alternative-responses-for-when-someone-sneezes)

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is that the only circumstances in which "health" is normally said as a one-word statement are those in which the generic uncountable noun "health" is the answer to a question. E.g.

> Questioner: What is the most important thing: money, or health?
>   Answerer: Health.

In English we don't say "Health!" in the circumstances you describe.

When someone sneezes, a standard response is "Bless you" (less commonly "God bless you", which is in a more formal register) or "[Gesundheit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gesundheit)".

When someone delivers a meal to your table, it's often accompanied by an imperative such as "Enjoy [your meal]!" or the salutation "Bon appetit!" which [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bon%20app%C3%A9tit) defines (with a diacritic):

> ***bon appétit*** French phrase
>   : good appetite : enjoy your meal

In English we simply never use the one-word statement "Health" as a salutation, blessing or wish. If used as a salutation, blessing or invocation, it would typically include a *determiner* to provide context; e.g.:

> "**[To] your health!**" (e.g. as an informal toast, often accompanied by the
>   bringing together of drinking vessels to create a pleasing "clink"
>   kind of sound)
>
> "**[To] the health of `(insert the name of someone important)`!**" (a more
>   formal toast, to which a standard response is to raise one's glass,
>   repeat the invocation, then take a drink).

Comment: In my experience the standard responses to sneezes are "bless you" and "gesundheit". People around here rarely say "God bless you" in response to sneezes even in church.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes, that rings true for me too. I've updated my answer accordingly. I do hear "God bless you" occasionally but this is more often from quite elderly folk, or as a more empathetic response to a particularly hearty sneeze - "God *bless* you!" :-)

Comment: "Gesundheit" is the German word "health"