# What is an alternative to "Bless you" after sneezing?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are alternative responses for when someone sneezes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31322/what-are-alternative-responses-for-when-someone-sneezes)

I know the history/reason [why people say *bless you*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14404/bless-you-sneezing) to you after you sneeze. My question is, is there an alternative to *bless you* which can be used when someone sneezes?

Comment: At least one answer is provided by the accepted answer of the linked questions...

Comment: _Gesundheit_ is German. I'm looking for an _English alternative_.

Comment: 'Gesundheit' is used by English speakers without knowing German. It has assimilated into English. It is not productive (you can't make new words with it in English) bit it is still recognized by English speakers. Therefore it _is_ English.

Comment: `Gesundheit` would be understood by pretty much any and all English speakers.  It's a German loanword that came in about a hundred years ago during one of the mass German migrations to the US.  Pretty sure the Brits and Aussies and whatnot would understand it as well.

Comment: I usually feign surprise for the heck of it.

Comment: As an aside, the French sometimes use a sequence of responses to multiple sneezes: "to your wishes" … "to your loves" … [exasperated] "to your death."

Comment: Good boy/girl. Now wipe that off my face.

Comment: Growing up it was always "cover your mouth!"

Comment: Never ever heard anyone say Gesundheit! If someone did I'd be like "sorry, come again?" not any German teacher or student. It must be a US only thing.

Comment: I don't think there's really a "right" answer to this--it's pretty subjective

Comment: You are sooo good looking (Seinfeld)

Comment: I normally say "Money!", because health most people already have. I often have to explain the joke too :)

Comment: Where, geographically are you asking about?  And in what geographic context?  Meaning are you asking about in Shanghai, but in an English boarding school? Or in Peru but in a Tibetan monastery? Or in Seattle in the Albertson Grocery's checkout line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've read that in polite company, you shouldn't say anything, so as to not draw any additional attention to the sneezer's faux pas.
As for alternatives to "bless you", I hear "Gesundheit" on TV a lot, but when I say it to people who just sneezed, they mostly don't seem to get it.

Comment: Far out, what social circles is sneezing a foh pah?

Answer (score 47):

The best alternative, I feel, is **simply to say nothing**. Saying "Bless you" (or *Gesundheit*, or anything else) after someone sneezes does, to some extent, oblige the sneezer to respond with thanks of some kind. This may be inconvenient, especially if the person is about to sneeze again, and such an exchange becomes downright silly in a chain of multiple sneezes — especially if, as often happens, the person is in another room, out of sight of the sneezer.

> **Me**: [Sneeze]
>   **You**: Bless you!
>   **Me**: Tha— [Sneeze]
>   **You**: Bless you!
>   **Me**: Thank [Sneeze] you.
>   **You**: Bless you!
>   **Me**: Tha— [Sneeze]
>   **You**: Bless you!
>   **Me**: [*Trying to find a tissue.*] Thank you.

I, for one, prefer to be allowed to sneeze my sneezes without being caught up in a social ritual that has no practical value.

Comment: +1 for the inspired dialogue that made me smile. Not at all far from reality...

Comment: +1 for the insight, -1 because it is not an answer about English but about common sense :)

Comment: @JeffSahol: Silence is always an option when using English. You might be surprised how often it's the best option.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6na5XtPLIN0

Comment: But let me say this. Once he passes on that option, that "god bless you" is up for grabs. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XbnQWrfgbvI

Comment: This answer is etiquette. The OP asked for an alternate word.

Comment: Thats why you look at the person and wait a bit before saying bless you, normally you can tell if they are going to resneeze, in which case you wait till after they've finished them all. But if someone sneezes on a train and you don't know them then just ignore them, unless your crammed in against each other and they look friendly.

Comment: Around here people always finish their sneezes before trying to respond.

Comment: By saying nothing you lose all the fun (as demonstrated in the answer). Additional fun is trying to say "bless you" *before* the person sneezes.

Comment: I give one "bless-you"/"gesundheit" per bout of sneezing. And, if I have a bout of sneezing, I give exactly one "thank-you" when I'm *done*. None of this sneeze-while-thanking-the-person nonsense.

Answer (score 35):

Gesundheit is a perfectly good alternative saying.

Comment: ... and is found in English dictionaries.

Comment: Rarely heard in British English though, have only really heard Americans (and Germans!) use it.

Comment: And doesn't clog up the com link with God with this human reflex to get the tickle out of your nose.

Comment: I have heard "**gesundheit**" all my life in Michigan, Iowa, and Texas. I suspect waves of German immigration transplanted the word here.

Comment: Wouldn't **krankheit** be more apt as a description?  That's what my co-worker always said when anyone sneezed because *gesundheit* was a bit of a misnomer.  :P

Comment: Of course ‘Gesundheit’ (health) is the correct thing to say, because that is what you wish for the person. If you say ‘Krankheit’ (sickness), I hope you know the person well enough so they don’t mind.

Answer (score 5):

I usually say "salud" (sa-lood) or "to health."

Answer (score 3):

I had a friend in high school that was a Native Indian, and took great offense to me blessing him after a sneeze. When I asked what he preferred instead, he responded, *"Your health."*

Comment: Who's a  Native Indian?